# In need of a possible phrase translation

Tags: phrase

How do you translate "The Internet of Things" into German. I have a suspicion that this a certain phrase, but I can't find any info on it.
Thanks

Comment: Internet der Dinge (IdD) : https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_der_Dinge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the relevant IT literature it is translated to "Internet der Dinge".  "Allesnetz" is not very common.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would say: "Internet der Dinge"

But I've also heard: "Allesnetz", which I like more!

Comment: Mit Artikel: Das Internet der Dinge